# Repeated citations in a paragraph with different postexts

Tags: biblatex, citing

I'm using the alphabetic style from biblatex.
I have lots of citations from the same source in one paragraph.
For example,

```
blablba, see \cite[prop.~12]{AB12}, and blabla, see \cite[prop.~34]{AB12}. Also, blabla from \cite[prop.~56]{AB12}.
```

So the output looks like:

> blablba, see [AB12, prop. 12], and blabla, see [AB12, prop. 34]. Also, blabla from [AB12, prop. 56].

It contains lots of duplicated "AB12". If I remember correctly, people usually use [loc.cit., prop. 34] or even shorter [l.c., prop. 34] in such situation.

My question is:
**How to let biblatex recognise repeated citations and replease them by "l.c."?**

Comment: Problem solved?

Answer (score 1):

The feature you are referring to is usually called ibidem (or ibid.) feature in `biblatex`. Repeated citations to the same work are replaced by "ibid.". `biblatex` also has a loccit feature to print "loc. cit.", but that is usually used slightly differently.

Unlike `authoryear` and `authortitle`, the standard `alphabetic` style does not come with a `-ibid` version that provides the ibidem feature out of the box. It has to be added manually. (I don't think I have ever seen "ibid." in an `alphabtic` or `numeric` style. You don't save a lot of space with it anyway.)

Here is how that could work with "ibid."

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=alphabetic, ibidtracker=true]{biblatex}

\providecommand*{\mkibid}[1]{#1}
\letbibmacro{cite:normal}{cite}
\newbibmacro*{cite:ibid}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{\bibstring[\mkibid]{ibidem}}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:normal}}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite[prop.~12]{sigfridsson}
ipsum \autocite[prop.~13]{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem [SR98, prop. 12] ipsum [ibid., prop. 13]]

If you prefer "l.c." or "loc.cit.", you can redefine the "ibidem" bibstring

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{ibidem = {l\adddot c\adddot}}
```